# Unable to build caffe2 AICamera app

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, clang++, caffe2

While trying to build [AICamera app](https://github.com/caffe2/AICamera) master branch, we failed to link the required native-lib library.

```
native-lib.cpp:144: error: undefined reference to 'caffe2::Predictor::run(std::__ndk1::vector<caffe2::Tensor<caffe2::CPUContext>*, std::__ndk1::allocator<caffe2::Tensor<caffe2::CPUContext>*> > const&, std::__ndk1::vector<caffe2::Tensor<caffe2::CPUContext>*, std::__ndk1::allocator<caffe2::Tensor<caffe2::CPUContext>*> >*)'
```

You can see the full traceback [here](https://pastebin.com/jQeHykhn)

Please advise

Android studio: 3.1.3

NDK: 17.1.4828580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with Android studio version. The app cant be compiled using it. Switching to 3.0.1 solved the problem.
Also, switching to NDK 13b helps with compiling it properly.